# How do I access SharedWithMe items on my OneDrive using REST API for Office365/Sharepoint?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, ms-office, office365, onedrive

How can I access items(files/folders) present under the **Shared with me** tab on my OneDrive(Office365)? I need to know the REST API end point for it.

I'm able to access those items that reside under the **Documents** tab (i.e, all user items) and I need to know if I can access those items that are under **Shared with me**

By definition these are those items that are explicitly shared with me hence they won't be showing in the **Document** items I get for my OneDrive.

Much appreciated.

Comment: You can't do this right now with the Office 365 Files REST API. I don't know if you can using the SharePoint 2013 REST API.

Comment: Already answered in the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28476449/625948